# SQL скрипт для создания БД

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Решаю тестовое задание и у меня там есть такой пункт:

*Технологии, которые необходимо использовать: 
Сервер БД MySQL;
SQL скрипт для создания БД; 
Технология JDBC для доступа к БД.*

Я, конечно, извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но что мне подозревать под SQL скриптом для создания БД? У меня есть несколько вариантов по этому поводу:

1. Файл *.sql где я пропишу sql команды по созданию необходимых мне таблиц в БД
2. Класс с методом main, где я через JDBC создам подключение к БД и необходимые таблицы.
3. Забей, делай любым из первых 2-х вариантов.
4. Это важно, уточняй у роботодателя.

Заранее спасибо. Как это сделать я знаю. Не уверен какой вариант нужно делать и насколько это принципиально.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал 4 вариант

Comment: а еще есть вот такая прекрасная вещь - http://www.liquibase.org/ очень удобно описывать БД и изменения БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В задании чётко описаны инструменты и объекты, которые необходимо использовать. Поэтому решение имхо должно быть таким:

1) *Сервер БД MySQL* -предполагается, что он уже есть, по этому пункту никакие действия не требуются. Если нет - проинсталлировать, возможно, организовав загрузку инсталлятора с официального сайта (хотя вряд ли задание требует, чтобы приложение устанавливало сервер при его отсутствии), или по крайней мере сообщить, что MySQL недоступен, и неплохо бы с этим разобраться.

2) *SQL-скрипт для создания БД* - необходимо написАть. Именно в формате .SQL - ну то есть команды создания БД (и, вероятно, таблиц в ней, возможно, даже с заполнением данными таблиц-справочников с предопределённым содержимым) в обычном текстовом файле. Создавать - да хоть с нуля в блокноте, хоть создать БД требуемой структуры и начального наполнения любыми средствами (скажем, штатным WorkBench) и затем получить дамп. Должен получиться один (или несколько) текстовый файл. Расширение в общем неважно, но лучше, если оно будет .SQL.

3) *JDBC для доступа к БД* - полагаю, имеется в виду создание приложения, которое в методе или классе либо считает файл .SQL и построчно организует выполнение его на сервере, используя для доступа JDBC, либо организует загрузку файла .SQL в файловую систему MySQL-сервера (если он не локальный) и с использованием JDBC подаст команду на выполнение скрипта (`source script.sql;`).

Comment: Могли бы Вы в двух словах о _"затем получить дамп"_. Все остально понятно - так и сделаю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` генерирует тот самый скрипт для создания *БД*. Вам его нужно только выполнить через `JDBC`

Comment: А как создать БД, из которой mysqldump сгенерирует скрипт, который нужно только выполнить через JDBC?

Comment: @Sergey не понял вопроса. Взять и выполнить скрипт. Он и создаст Вам базу

Comment: Первый раз БД придётся создавать вручную. Хотите - используйте визуальные средства (да хоть бы и workbench), хотите - пишите руками (как по мне - предпочтитльный вариант, ибо обеспечивает 100% контроля). Ну а дальше любой дампер.